# Asp net core - from model to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing an asp net core application.
What I want to achieve is to read the model inside the view with Javascript.
I found this code but when I run it i receive this error:

> 'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

how can i fix it?

**controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Bolla.ToListAsync());
}
```

**view**

```
@model IEnumerable<ps0001.Models.Bolla>

<script>
    var bolla = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using this in your `view` instead:

```
@model IEnumerable<ps0001.Models.Bolla>

<script>
    var bolla = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))';
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

In order to view the contents, parse the extracted `Model` using the following:

`var parseModel = JSON.parse(bolla);`

Then you will be able to use the object and whatever attributes it contains.

Comment: Thank you sandman. I tried with ---
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
alert(model[0].Anno); ---
and now in the alert I got "undefined"

Comment: In order to access the variable, you may have to parse. Try: `var parseModel = JSON.parse(bolla);` and use the console window to view the result.

Comment: Thanks @Sandman, I've been tearing my hair out for the last few hours, this sorted my issue!

Comment: When I tried var parseModel = JSON.parse(bolla); and I got the following error
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 39 of the JSON data
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
    <anonymous> http://localhost:9318/Controller/Action?userID=1:370
    jQuery 13